# Data Layer based clustering solution

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I have taken a look at the Google Maps v3 Utility Libraries and found the `MarkerClusterer` and `MarkerManager` libraries.However,I am reading and writing data using multiple `google.maps.Data` layers.

Is there any way to perform clustering for `POINT` features on these layers(which might be loaded dynamically from public sources as well as application data) without converting the data to markers??

Can we do the marker clustering on the server side while loading the data using an AJAX request?

Comment: Clustering is a relatively complex task that you don't really want to be running server side.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW Is there any client side solution/hack available for the client side using `Data` layers which is like a new feature of the API?

Comment: @Jonno_FTW why **wouldn't** you want to run complex tasks on the server?

Comment: Because it will increase server load unnecessarily and thus increase page load time and it's work that you can't really cache and chances are that the user has more power than the server can divvy up between clients.

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but I had exactly the same problem and it took me quite long to find a solution to this.

You can use https://github.com/Connum/data-layer-clusterer, which I just enhanced to make it work for LineString and Polygon features as well.

Here's a working example:

```js
window.initMap = function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 49.0192242, lng: 8.4051448},
  zoom: 13,
  scaleControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  rotateControl: false,
  });

  var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
  s.setAttribute( 'src', 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/Connum/data-layer-clusterer/master/src/datalayerclusterer.js' );
  s.async = false;
  document.head.appendChild( s );
  s.onload = function() {
var cluster = new DataLayerClusterer({
"map": map
  });

  cluster.addGeoJson({
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.404455900017638,
  49.013533476349956
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.401044130150694,
  49.01396272155595
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.400035619561095,
  49.01183053267183
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.40565752965631,
  49.01064125233564
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.402932405297179,
  49.01073977367939
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.403726339165587,
  49.01247793961102
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.404820680443663,
  49.01244275466763
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.404724120919127,
  49.01104237373055
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.403586864296813,
  49.011105708392215
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.409692287095822,
  49.012400532702735
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.411816596635617,
  49.014638247499114
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.409027099260129,
  49.017537275583216
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.398555755265988,
  49.01670698867642
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.396946429857053,
  49.0123160886655
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39379215205554,
  49.00865670946874
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.411065578111447,
  49.00868485956599
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.413211345323361,
  49.01026123961204
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.400143623002805,
  49.007558843262004
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.400422572740354,
  49.00857225908148
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.403812884935178,
  49.007882575557474
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.407074451097287,
  49.007404014028836
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.407546519883908,
  49.00957157948308
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.407310485490598,
  49.013976795106586
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.40351247752551,
  49.017354332200135
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.404177665361203,
  49.019043014809284
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.402332305558957,
  49.01567966536862
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.397225379594602,
  49.015496715158264
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.393341540941037,
  49.01674920698892
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39402818644885,
  49.01396272155595
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39276218379382,
  49.01209090386598
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.395551681169309,
  49.011443491893736
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39874887431506,
  49.0145256604785
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.402203559526242,
  49.01627073068373
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.408447742112912,
  49.016692915897615
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.409306048997678,
  49.0153278374442
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.415936469682492,
  49.01649589657675
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.415357112535276,
  49.012766455208926
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.41200971568469,
  49.01306200603891
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.410357474931516,
  49.011654605418435
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.407396316179074,
  49.01235831070202
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.410293101915158,
  49.01456788064106
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.40773963893298,
  49.01587668792012
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.405186175950803,
  49.01569373843385
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.404306411393918,
  49.01508859303522
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.403319358476438,
  49.01711509753079
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.400486945756711,
  49.018578632802985
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.398040771135129,
  49.018409765544675
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.395895003923215,
  49.01842383783808
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.395830630906858,
  49.017058806853235
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.395422935136594,
  49.01586261490659
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.396324157365598,
  49.013807912236224
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.399542808183469,
  49.01334348138857
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.401259421953,
  49.01332940765888
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.398469924577512,
  49.01033161255747
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.396731853135861,
  49.01048643268729
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39701080287341,
  49.00864263441412
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.394135474809445,
  49.008389282751025
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.392955302842893,
  49.01043013451395
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.396152495988645,
  49.0076714460383
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.409713744767942,
  49.00689729680877
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.412074088701047,
  49.0073617877908
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.401259421953,
  49.006489104187075
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.424090385087766,
  49.01138719480263
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.421644210466184,
  49.01417382439788
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.418425559648313,
  49.016692915897615
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.41848993266467,
  49.017452840259196
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.419884681352414,
  49.01233016268164
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.417266845353879,
  49.01024716501104
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.414949416765012,
  49.00891005977109
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.41548585856799,
  49.00754476789709
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.425055980333127,
  49.00778404855994
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.42400455439929,
  49.01266793787567
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.421322345384397,
  49.00872708468202
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.419906139024533,
  49.00692544790073
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.418447017320432,
  49.00776997325865
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.417803287156858,
  49.01261164216915
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.416365623124875,
  49.016186293211256
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.4132542606676,
  49.01772021829393
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.411816596635617,
  49.017072879528584
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.41151618922595,
  49.01614407442129
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.413425922044553,
  49.01358273418453
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39201116526965,
  49.018466054694436
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.390830993303098,
  49.01575003065509
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.388749599107541,
  49.017143242845684
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.38954353297595,
  49.0135123658345
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.389693736680783,
  49.01230201464536
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.389350413926877,
  49.01059902884291
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.389672279008664,
  49.00931823254672
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39078807795886,
  49.00789665082693
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.392354488023557,
  49.007178807012075
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.397461413987912,
  49.00696767450883
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
  [
    [
      8.399607181199826,
      49.01534191060892
    ],
    [
      8.399907588609494,
      49.01462417413546
    ],
    [
      8.400615691789426,
      49.01448344028011
    ],
    [
      8.401087760576047,
      49.01470861425769
    ],
    [
      8.401109218248166,
      49.01489156736447
    ],
    [
      8.40050840342883,
      49.01529969110284
    ],
    [
      8.400486945756711,
      49.015947052928105
    ],
    [
      8.399607181199826,
      49.01534191060892
    ]
  ]
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
  [
    [
      8.404563903459348,
      49.017143242845684
    ],
    [
      8.404220580705442,
      49.01641145948622
    ],
    [
      8.40449953044299,
      49.016073709691824
    ],
    [
      8.4057440754259,
      49.01614407442129
    ],
    [
      8.405593871721067,
      49.01710102486738
    ],
    [
      8.40527200663928,
      49.01691807988091
    ],
    [
      8.404885768541135,
      49.01700251611205
    ],
    [
      8.404885768541135,
      49.017255823946115
    ],
    [
      8.404563903459348,
      49.017143242845684
    ]
  ]
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
  [
    [
      8.41321277548559,
      49.00502521347455
    ],
    [
      8.412912368075922,
      49.00454662448421
    ],
    [
      8.41943550040014,
      49.002829296715134
    ],
    [
      8.421752928989008,
      49.000745901563036
    ],
    [
      8.423169135348871,
      49.0011682184338
    ],
    [
      8.42419910361059,
      49.002688529517854
    ],
    [
      8.41321277548559,
      49.00502521347455
    ]
  ]
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "LineString",
"coordinates": [
  [
    8.387935637729242,
    49.01496193376498
  ]
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "LineString",
"coordinates": [
  [
    8.387420653598383,
    49.01051458175004
  ],
  [
    8.38797855307348,
    49.01499008029734
  ],
  [
    8.38849353720434,
    49.016932152596056
  ],
  [
    8.38948059012182,
    49.01873342728651
  ],
  [
    8.391798018710688,
    49.02092864268258
  ],
  [
    8.394544600741938,
    49.02247649276904
  ],
  [
    8.397162436740473,
    49.023461463214126
  ],
  [
    8.400381087558344,
    49.02413686025233
  ],
  [
    8.402655600802973,
    49.02436199056141
  ],
  [
    8.406260489718989,
    49.02419314292509
  ],
  [
    8.410079955356196,
    49.02323632883109
  ],
  [
    8.412096976535395,
    49.022392065823794
  ],
  [
    8.414414405124262,
    49.02081606988936
  ],
  [
    8.41673183371313,
    49.019043014809284
  ],
  [
    8.418105124728754,
    49.016481823738275
  ],
  [
    8.418276786105707,
    49.01403308926939
  ],
  [
    8.418105124728754,
    49.011274600429445
  ],
  [
    8.417547225253657,
    49.00967010294351
  ],
  [
    8.417289733188227,
    49.008881909801154
  ],
  [
    8.387420653598383,
    49.01051458175004
  ]
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.399053572211415,
  49.02233578111405
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.399311064276844,
  49.02593787420766
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39467620709911,
  49.02886438286371
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.393732069525868,
  49.02357403002371
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.387294767890126,
  49.023011193429554
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.387809752020985,
  49.02661323763608
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.406005857978016,
  49.025375064348665
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.41639137128368,
  49.022898625346855
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.403001783881336,
  49.02092864268258
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39793777326122,
  49.02295490942005
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.409868238959461,
  49.02216692660292
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.424030302558094,
  49.02441827297955
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.426433561835438,
  49.02644439763833
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.428236006293446,
  49.023011193429554
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.418708799872547,
  49.0211537875052
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.417764662299305,
  49.022898625346855
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.424030302558094,
  49.0204220631079
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.428750990424305,
  49.01591890693685
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.43312835553661,
  49.019465176509826
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.435703276190907,
  49.02087235631782
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.424802778754383,
  49.01907115903407
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.387552259955555,
  49.0211537875052
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.38120078900829,
  49.0172136060633
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.38145828107372,
  49.01597519890346
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.385234831366688,
  49.016481823738275
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.38368987897411,
  49.02087235631782
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.384033201728016,
  49.019746615654235
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.383604048285633,
  49.0249248118783
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.3859214768745,
  49.02644439763833
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.423171995673329,
  49.01839569324728
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.419481276068836,
  49.021604074094846
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.408237455878407,
  49.021604074094846
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.39665031293407,
  49.020984928983715
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.387723921332508,
  49.022673488417595
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.390813826117665,
  49.02199807151889
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.390899656806141,
  49.02644439763833
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.40566253522411,
  49.0284141619659
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.40214347699657,
  49.02593787420766
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.401199339423329,
  49.0291457688561
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.41115569928661,
  49.02706347482933
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.41415977338329,
  49.02441827297955
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.409181593451649,
  49.02633183732152
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.418107985053211,
  49.02756998680219
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.421197889838368,
  49.02520622014968
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.415189741645008,
  49.027119754192036
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.416992186103016,
  49.02610671592411
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.384462355170399,
  49.01394864800132
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.385320662055165,
  49.01254127244647
]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
  8.424974440131336,
  49.01681957076354
]
  }
}
]
});
  }
  
}

var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
s.setAttribute( 'src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap' );
s.async = false;
document.head.appendChild( s );
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```